# In .XResources with the VT100 translations resource, what is the difference between <Key> and <KeyPress>

Tags: x11, xterm, x-resources

I'm trying to do the classic endeavor of binding key sequences to do copy and paste.  In this case, it is xterm and I have my keyboard such that (I believe) I want Super-C to copy and Super-V to paste (yes. I have a Super key defined in my xmodmap).

I see different examples doing different tasks and some have `<Key>` and some have `<KeyPress>` -- and of course `<KeyRelease>`.  I'd like to know what the difference is between them.

More generally, I'd like to know the syntax of the "translations" resource.  As I recall, it is very versatile and can have states, etc.  I knew this back during the Great War (vi .vs. emacs) but I've forgotten it all by now.

Update:

With some experimentation, I believe the following solves the original quest of getting copy and paste to work but not the main objective of this question.  I would still very much like to know the difference between `<Key>` and `<KeyPress>` and the general syntax for the `translations` resource

```
*VT100*translations:      #override \n\
    Super <Key>C:       copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Super <Key>V:       insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key`, `KeyPress` and `KeyDown` are the same feature (see [table](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxt/-/blob/master/src/TMparse.c#L247) in `TMParse.c`).

For documentation... it seems that most of that is for the X Toolkit library interface, in [chapter 10](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xtoolkit/intrinsics.html#Translation_Management).  I don't see anything useful in [X(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/x).